# Can malware have signed code?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

When I run an exe that has signed code on Windows, I feel kind of safe. But I wonder if walware can have signed code?
According this [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mmpc/2008/11/07/malware-and-signed-code/)

> Microsoft Authenticode® is a technology that can help ensure the source of code.  It does not ensure that code is safe to run, but it can ensure that the code is associated with an entity in a trust chain.

Can walware's hacker just create a signed code for themselves to trick Windows that this software has signed code? How can Microsoft guarantee that only Certificate Authorities (CAs) can create signed code?

Comment: Additionally, can clone a chain of certificates. https://posts.specterops.io/code-signing-certificate-cloning-attacks-and-defenses-6f98657fc6ec

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Can malware have signed code?

Yes.

Many pieces of malware have been signed, including Stuxnet, and the malware recently bundled with CCleaner have been signed, in the case of Stuxnet this was *probably* done by stealing the signing certificate, whereas in the case of the CCleaner attack it seems it was done by infecting the build server, so that it would inject malware in before signing the release.

## How can Microsoft guarantee that only Certificate Authorities (CAs) can create signed code?

The CAs do not directly create code, they issue certificates, which developers then use to sign their executables.

For example, if FooBar Widgets released an app, they could sign it with a certificate like this:

```
Root CA
   Intermediate CA
       FooBar Widgets
```

If your computer trusts the Root CA then it will trust the certicate for FooBar Widgets, and show the signed prompt for the program, instead of the unsigned one.

As such there are 4 main ways to try to get around this form of code signing:

- Break the signing scheme (like Flame did)
- Trick the CA into making a fake cert (More common in SSL certs)
- Steal the Signing Cert (Stuxnet style)
- Trick the company into signing your malware (CCLeaner style)

## References

- [Stuxnet-style code signing is more widespread than anyone thought](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/11/evasive-code-signed-malware-flourished-before-stuxnet-and-still-does/)
- [Analyzing the MD5 collision in Flame](https://trailofbits.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/flame-md5.pdf)
- [Inside 'Operation Black Tulip': DigiNotar hack analysed](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/06/diginotar_audit_damning_fail/)
- [Avast urges devs to secure toolchains after hacked build box led to CCleaner disaster](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/10/06/ccleaner_megahack_timeline/)

Comment: So... the signed code system is not really trustful - or it's useless?

Comment: It acts as another layer of defence, and coupling with a small set of trusted CAs, or pined certs like for android apps can make attacking even harder.

Comment: On the negative side, in places where it is made mandatory it can be used to lock people out of running their own code on their own devices.

Comment: Ok, so what I understand is: signed code make it hard for malware, but not impossible.

Comment: Yes, it means you don't just have to make malware, but then somehow get it signed also.

Comment: Getting a code signing certificate isn't any more difficult than getting an EV certificate. And since few people actually checks anything about the code signing cert itself,  it makes the whole thing rather ineffective as a security measure. In locked gardens, at least, the signing is done by a third party who was supposed to vet the code.